# How to fix "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging, sprite-kit

I have a Sprite Kit Game in Swift. 
After I updated Xcode and opened my project, I noticed some changes and an error to a pre-coded syntax saying: "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" which wasn't there before. 
I marked the code with error below. Also Xcode says it's something wrong with `.DataReadingMappedIfSafe`. 
Do you know a way to fix it? 
Thank you in advance!

```
import UIKit
import SpriteKit

extension SKNode {
  class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) -> SKNode? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {

      // Error occurs on the following line:
      var sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe, error: nil)!

      var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData)
      archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
      let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
      archiver.finishDecoding()
      return scene
    } else {
      return nil
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you updated your question with the code causing the error.

Comment: OK. I just updated with the codes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
class func unarchiveFromFile(file : String) -> SKNode? {
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "sks") {

        var sceneData: NSData?
        // Error occurs on the following line:
        do {
            sceneData = try  NSData(contentsOfFile: path, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)
        } catch _ as NSError {

        }

        var archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: sceneData!)
        archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
        let scene = archiver.decodeObjectForKey(NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! GameScene
        archiver.finishDecoding()
        return scene
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `try` from Swift 2, see the *Swift 2* iBook.The Swift 2.0 declaration is: `convenience init(contentsOfFile path: String, encoding enc: UInt) throws`, note the `throws` in place of the error parameter.

> Error Handling
>
> Error handling is the process of responding to and recovering from error conditions in your program. Swift provides first-class support for throwing, catching, propagating, and manipulating recoverable errors at runtime.”

You can learn more on Error Handling in Swift from the book: “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2.1).” iBooks. https://itun.es/de/1u3-0.l

But in any case ignoring errors is not a best practice.